# Can I access my gmusic library from a custom chromecast receiver?

Tags: google-chrome, chromecast

I would like to build a custom jukebox to play my Google Music Standard or All Access via my account on my custom receiver using my standard google credentials.  Not sure if the MediaPlayerLibrary has the interfaces that can do that so I can get the stream.  Just looking for the best way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, Google doesn't offer and api for Google Music but there have been projects that unofficially reverse engineer ways to get the music.

Ex. https://github.com/simon-weber/Unofficial-Google-Music-API

Comment: Thanks.  Yes, I've seen Simon's project, and although I have not been through it in detail yet, from what I've seen an ANDROID_ID that's registered to your gmail account is required to get an actual stream.

Comment: You can use the webclient interface for streaming in this case, which doesn't require a device id: http://unofficial-google-music-api.readthedocs.org/en/develop/reference/webclient.html#gmusicapi.clients.Webclient.get_stream_audio.